# combining elements into one table cell with same name MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
id   |   name |   description1   |  description2
--------------------------------------------------
1    |  bob   |   he is tall.    | he is smart.
2    |  bob   |   he is fat.     | he is big.
3    |  john  |   he is white.   | he is also tall.
4    | brian  |   he is asian    | he is the tallest.
5    | john   |   he is second.  | he is dumb.
```

I want to combine the two columns, but then want to combine the rows based the names, so it ends up like this:

```
id   |   name |   combined_description   
--------------------------------------------------
1    |  bob   |   he is tall. he is smart. he is fat. he is big. 
3    |  john  |   he is white. he is also tall. he is second. he is dumb.
4    | brian  |   he is asian. he is the tallest.
```

I know combining columns "description1" and "description2" is easy enough, but how would I combine rows based on having the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    min(id) as id,
    name,
    group_concat(description1, ' ', description2 order by id separator ' ') as combined_description
from your_table
group by name;
```

But group_concat will truncate the results at @@group_concat_max_len characters, which is often 1024.  So you may need to set that to a higher value before doing the query.